Handwritten Text Line Segmentation
I am writing a program to segment the different lines from a cropped image of paragraph with handwritten text. This is my current code which works in most cases but sometimes struggles and combines several lines into one.
import cv2
import os
from tqdm import tqdm


def segment_lines(image_path):
    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if img is None:
        print(f"Error: Unable to load image at {image_path}")
        return []

    # Create base output folder
    base_output_folder = 'segmented_lines'
    os.makedirs(base_output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Create image-specific output folder inside the base folder
    base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(image_path))[0]
    image_output_folder = os.path.join(base_output_folder, base_name)
    os.makedirs(image_output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply binary inverse thresholding
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # Define the structuring element for dilation
    dilate_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,
                                              (50, 1))  # Wider but shorter kernel to connect words horizontally
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, dilate_kernel)

    # Apply erosion to reduce noise and separate lines
    erode_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 5))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, erode_kernel)

    # Apply a second dilation to rejoin any broken parts of lines
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, dilate_kernel)

    # Find contours and filter using hierarchy
    bboxes = []
    bboxes_img = img.copy()
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cntr in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        if w > 50 and h > 10:  # Filter out small contours that are likely noise
            cv2.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
            bboxes.append((x, y, w, h))

    # Save each segmented line as an individual image with a progress bar
    for j, (x, y, w, h) in enumerate(tqdm(bboxes, desc="Saving segmented lines")):
        # Ensure the bounding box is within image dimensions
        x1 = max(x - 10, 0)
        y1 = max(y - 10, 0)
        x2 = min(x + w + 10, img.shape[1])
        y2 = min(y + h + 10, img.shape[0])

        crop = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

        if crop.size > 0:
            cv2.imwrite(f'{image_output_folder}/line_{j}.jpg', crop)

    # Save the final image with bounding boxes
    cv2.imwrite(f'{image_output_folder}/segmented_lines_with_boxes.jpg', bboxes_img)

    print(f"Segmented lines saved in the folder '{image_output_folder}'")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path = 'img/2.png'
    segment_lines(image_path)

I tried tuning the OpenCV parameters but this gives the best result.

Please include your test images; otherwise your code is not reproducible.
